# How to make a text float vertically?

Tags: html, css

[image]
[image]
How to make my text like this?

I tried rotating just first word with `<span>` `transform: rotated(-90deg)` but i get some blur on other text and cant make it just like in photo. Also tried rotating first word as single `<p>` but then i can't wrap other text around it.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of float and writing-mode can do it:

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

p span {
  float: left;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  scale: -1;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>First Word</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nec lacus sed arcu viverra aliquet vel non eros. Mauris vehicula purus vel pretium cursus. Mauris commodo justo vitae mollis mollis. Vivamus dapibus nec ipsum eu interdum.
  Suspendisse potenti. Donec efficitur non enim id faucibus. Aenean volutpat aliquam tincidunt. Cras dapibus diam et mi iaculis pretium.</p>
```